# Ordering of Sequel (gem) subqueries

Tags: ruby, sequel

I am looking for a way to concatenate subqueries with a specific ordering.

The following query:

```
User.where(a: 3).where(#<Sequel::SQL::BooleanExpression @op=>:"NOT IN", @args=>[:b, [0.25, 0.31, 0.78]]>).or(b: nil)
```

groups like so:

```
(((a == 3) AND (b != [...]))
OR (b == nil))
```

However what I am trying to achieve is

```
((a == 3) 
AND ((b != [...]) OR (b == nil))
```

Any ideas how one can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
User.where(:a=>3).where(Sequel.~(:b=>[0.25, 0.31, 0.78]) | {:b=>nil})
```